# Amazon IAM users signed URL's for access through CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to create CloudFront signed url's for users created in IAM using their access key and secret key?

I can create them using the root credentials but not with IAM users because they don't have a .pem file with their private key.

Is there something that I am missing or is this even possible? I've searched around but can't find any info that has helped me.

Thanks

Comment: Signed URLs for which service?

Comment: Apologies for leaving that out, it's for CloudFront

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that it's not possible.

You have to create CloudFront Key-Pair for the trusted signer. See details here ... http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html#private-content-creating-cloudfront-key-pairs